# wrap-params (cljs-ajax + compojure)

Tags: ajax, clojure, clojurescript, compojure

Consider the following compojure routing:

```
(defroutes main-routes
  (POST "/something" r {:body (prn-str (:params r))}))

(def handler
  (-> main-routes
      (wrap-params)))
```

When testing this with `curl` I'm getting the desired result:

```
curl -d "a=b" localhost:3000/something
{"a" "b"}
```

The Post parameters are read by compojure and wrapped to the params-map.

However this does not work with an ajax request initiated by the cljs-ajax library:

```
(POST "/something" {:handler #(js/alert %)
                    :params {"a" "b"}})
```

It alerts "`{}`". When changing the code to use GET, it works however. I guess this is due to the fact, that the browser sends the body as an input stream and not as plain text. But I'm not sure and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Perhaps you could try setting `{... :format :raw ...}` in the cljs-ajax call?

Comment: You checked that when using cljs-ajax a `PUT` request is sent instead of a `POST` ? Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `cljs-ajax` is sending a `transit`-formatted request and response by default. (See `:format` and `:response-format` defaults [here](https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax#getpostput)). You might try specifying an explicit json response in the request map -

```
{:handler #(js/alert %)
 :params {"a" "b"}
 :response-format :json}
```

Comment: This is correct. There's a detect format that will read the response headers. It's only not the default because it involves including a lot of code in the client js.